# SQLite : Need reference to "current" row in a UPDATE

Tags: sqlite, subquery, in-subquery

I'm working with a SQLite table representing a tree.  Its columns include `id` and `parent`.  Of course, each `parent` value is the `id` of another row.

There is also a `changeCount` column, which I must increment by 1 for each child deleted in a bulk operation.

For example, say that

- Rows with id 11, 12 and 13 are going to be deleted in a bulk operation.
- The rows with id=11 and id=12 both have the same parent=5.
- The row with id=13 has parent=8.

Then the row with id=5 should have its changeCount incremented by 2, and the row with id=8 should have its changeCount incremented by 1.

It seems like there should be a way to do this in one query.  Maybe something like this:

```
UPDATE myTable
    SET changeCount = changeCount
    + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable
       WHERE id IN (11,12,13) AND parent = XXXX);
```

Expression XXXX should be a reference to the "current" row; that whose changeCount is being set.  Is there an expression for that?  Or is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: SQLite is an embedded database, and designed to be used together with a 'real' programming language. Why do you want to avoid multiple SQL statements?

Comment: Interesting comment, @CL!  To be honest with you, 98% of my experience is with 'real' programming languages.  With SQLite, I've always been a simple SELECT and UPDATE kind of a guy, envious of those database gurus who, it seems, can express quite complicated requirements with a single fancy SQL statement.  When I ran into this here requirement, I thought it would be only intermediate level, so I'd give fancy SQL a shot.  Maybe I underestimated the difficulty of this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @CL, I've herein edited my previous working but messy answer into one that looks pretty decent:

```
UPDATE myTable
  SET changeCount = changeCount
    + ifnull( 
      (SELECT theCount FROM (SELECT parent AS theParent, COUNT(*) AS theCount FROM myTable WHERE id IN (11,12,13) GROUP BY parent) WHERE theParent = id)
      , 0);
```

The reason for the `ifnull()` is that the `id` at the end of Line 4 makes that a correlated subquery, which is evaluated for each row in the table, and for rows which are not having any children deleted, it evaluates to NULL.

I wonder if performance could be improved by using two queries instead, first running the subquery (Line 4) as a standalone query, returning to the program a dictionary whose keys are the ids of parents with children being deleted and values are how many of its children are being deleted.  But my question was how to do this in one query :)

**UPDATE: THE ABOVE IS OK FOR HOME BUT DON'T TRY IT AT WORK**

I should have given more thought to the original comment by @CL.  Although this answer works, performance on a real SQLite database containing tens of thousands of rows was horrible.

**LESSON: Fancy SQL queries such as this "answer" are interesting brain teasers, but in practice, if performance matters, if you have a *real* programming language available, you should instead use simple queries and do your processing in the *real* language.**

That's what I ended up doing in the real-life case from which this question arose.

Comment: [ifnull()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) might help.

Comment: Indeed it does, @CL!  Regarding your comment on the question, it's kind of ironic that none of the 'real' programming languages I've dealt with have such a function.